# Filters on Multiple Column in BigTable

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

From CBT's documentation

```
// READING OP HERE
timestamp := bigtable.Now()
mut := bigtable.NewMutation()
mut.Set(columnFamilyName, "os_name", timestamp, []byte("android"))

filter := bigtable.ChainFilters(
    bigtable.FamilyFilter(columnFamilyName),
    bigtable.ColumnFilter("os_build"),
    bigtable.ValueFilter("PQ2A\\..*"))
conditionalMutation := bigtable.NewCondMutation(filter, mut, nil)

rowKey := "phone#4c410523#20190501"
if err := tbl.Apply(ctx, rowKey, conditionalMutation); err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("Apply: %v", err)
}

fmt.Println("Successfully updated row's os_name")
```

I wanted to know if this also enables concurrency control, i.e. if we go by sequence
#1 - Read
#2 - Modify on Read
#3 - Write

If two threads are trying to modify same row at same time, will tbl.Apply fail?

Answer (score 0):

The process of checking and then writing as a conditional mutation is completed as a single, atomic action. If you are sending multiple mutations they could get executed in an arbitrary order, but since the conditionalMutation is a single action it wont be affected by another mutation. Therefore, tbl.Apply should not fail in your case.